# Convex hull proof

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science, computational-geometry, convex-hull

How to formal prove that convex hull can not be found in better time then O(n log n). I know that it is true, from connection with sorting. So if it is not true that would mean we can sort set of n points in time better then O( n log n), since we can sort using convex hull algorithm, and we know that is not possible. But how to formal prove that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for a mathematical proof, not a computer program.

Comment: Caution: the n Log n bound for sorting only holds for comparison-based algorithms. If other operations are allowed (like in Radix Sort), better bounds are possible. The hull can be obtained by sorting, then applying the Graham's walk, which takes linear time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that a convex hull algorithm is expected to output the vertices of the convex hull either in clockwise or anti-clockwise order - i.e. the output of the algorithm is a polygon, and the polygon's vertices must be output in the right order.

So imagine you have a list of numbers; convert them to angles in the range 0 to 359 degrees by some appropriate scaling, so that each number corresponding to an angle `t` in the original list becomes a point at position `(1; t)` in [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates). The convex hull will necessarily include all of the points, and will necessarily be in sorted order, so if you can find the convex hull in `O(f(n))` time then you can sort in `O(n + f(n))` time, where the extra `n` term is the cost of transforming the numbers to angles and back.